Closed form for double integral involving Beta functions
Let $ n,m \in \mathbb{N}$ and $ r > 0 $. Consider the integral:
$$
\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{x^{n-1} (1-x)^{n-1} y^{m-1} (1-y)^{m-1}} {(x+y)^{m+n-r}} \, dx \, dy
$$
Is there a closed form for this? The problem originates from considerations of 2D beta functions, similar to what was discussed in this post.

Using Mathematica and Mellin Transform (Inverse Mellin Transform) we have only an analytic expression ,not closed-form solution:
$$\int _0^1\int _0^1(1-x)^{-1+n} x^{-1+n} (1-y)^{-1+m} y^{-1+m} (x+y)^{-m-n+r}dydx=\\\mathcal{M}_s^{-1}\left[\int _0^1\int _0^1\mathcal{M}_A\left[(1-x)^{-1+n} x^{-1+n} (1-y)^{-1+m} y^{-1+m} (x+A y)^{-m-n+r}\right](s)dydx\right](1)=\\\mathcal{M}_s^{-1}\left[\int _0^1\int
   _0^1\frac{(1-x)^{-1+n} x^{-1-m+r+s} (1-y)^{-1+m} y^{-1+m-s} \Gamma (m+n-r-s) \Gamma (s)}{\Gamma (m+n-r)}dydx\right](1)=\\\mathcal{M}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{\Gamma (m) \Gamma (n) \Gamma (m-s) \Gamma
   (m+n-r-s) \Gamma (s) \Gamma (-m+r+s)}{\Gamma (m+n-r) \Gamma (2 m-s) \Gamma (-m+n+r+s)}\right](1)=\frac{2^{1-2 m} \pi ^{3/2} \csc (\pi  (-m+r)) \Gamma (m) \Gamma (n) \, _3F_2(m,1+m-n-r,m+n-r;2 m,1+m-r;-1)}{\Gamma
   \left(\frac{1}{2}+m\right) \Gamma (1+m-r) \Gamma (-m+n+r)}+\frac{\pi  \csc (\pi  (m-r)) \Gamma (m) \Gamma (n) \Gamma (r) \, _3F_2(1-n,n,r;1-m+r,m+r;-1)}{\Gamma (m+n-r) \Gamma (1-m+r) \Gamma
   (m+r)}$$
Mathematica code:
F[m_, n_, r_] := NIntegrate[(1 - x)^(-1 + n) x^(-1 + n) (1 - y)^(-1 + m) y^(-1 + m) (x + y)^(-m - n + r), {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]

G[m_, n_, r_] := N[(2^(1 - 2 m) \[Pi]^(3/2)
  Csc[\[Pi] (-m + r)] Gamma[m] Gamma[
  n] HypergeometricPFQ[{m, 1 + m - n - r, m + n - r}, {2 m, 
   1 + m - r}, -1])/(
Gamma[1/2 + m] Gamma[
  1 + m - r] Gamma[-m + n + r]) + (\[Pi] Csc[\[Pi] (m - r)] 
Gamma[m] Gamma[n] Gamma[
  r] HypergeometricPFQ[{1 - n, n, r}, {1 - m + r, m + r}, -1])/(
Gamma[m + n - r] Gamma[1 - m + r] Gamma[m + r])];

{F[2, 3, 1/2], G[2, 3, 1/2]}
(*{0.103023, 0.103023}*)

